# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' (can't figure out which one)

Tags: php

This is the line:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) );  rel="bookmark"?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

I checked and I can't see the problem.

Comment: A nice method to solve stuff like this is splitting each command into its own line. However, in this case, it's `rel="bookmark"` inside the PHP tag

Comment: Most code editors with syntax highlighting make this sort of issue very easy to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
    title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"
    rel="bookmark">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is around `rel="bookmark"?>"`.